# Uniform Cost Search In Romania Map problem

Tags: python

I have written this code. This is a code of Uniform COst search. I have to find the path between Arad and Bucharest. My problem is that my code is giving the correct total cost that is 418. But I can not figure out how to find the path that is giving this cost. Any help is appreciated.
from queue import PriorityQueue

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.edges={"Arad":["Zerind","Timisoara","Sibiu"],"Zerind":["Oradea"],"Oradea":["Sibiu"],"Timisoara":["Lugoj"],"Lugoj":["Mehadia"],"Mehadia":["Dobreta"],"Dobreta":["Craiova"],"Sibiu":["Fagaras","RimnicuVilcea"],"Craiova":["RimnicuVilcea","Pitesti"],"RimnicuVilcea":["Craiova","Pitesti"],"Fagaras":["Bucharest"],"Pitesti":["Bucharest"],"Bucharest":["Giurgiu","Urziceni"],"Urziceni":["Hirsova","Vaslui"],"Hirsova":["Eforie"],"Vaslui":["Lasi"],"Lasi":["Neamt"]}
        self.weights={"AradZerind":75,"ZerindOradea":71,"AradTimisoara":118,"TimisoaraLugoj":111,"LugojMehadia":70,"MehadiaDobreta":75,"AradSibiu":140,"OradeaSibiu":151,"DobretaCraiova":120,"CraiovaRimnicuVilcea":146,"CraiovaPitesti":138,"SibiuFagaras":99,"SibiuRimnicuVilcea":80,"RimnicuVilceaPitesti":97,"RimnicuVilceaCraiova":146,"FagarasBucharest":211,"PitestiBucharest":101,"BucharestGiurgiu":90,"BucharestUrziceni":85,"UrziceniHirsova":98,"HirsovaEforie":86,"UrziceniVaslui":142,"VasluiLasi":92,"LasiNeamt":87}
    def neighbors(self,node):
        return self.edges[node]
    def get_cost(self,from_node,to_node):
        return self.weights[(from_node + to_node)]



def ucs(graph, start, goal):
    global total_cost
    visited = set()
    path=[]
    queue = PriorityQueue()
    queue.put((0, start))
    while queue:
        cost, node = queue.get()
        if node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            if node == goal:
                return visited
            for i in graph.neighbors(node):
                if i not in visited:
                    total_cost = cost + graph.get_cost(node, i)
                    queue.put((total_cost, I)


graph=Graph()
s=ucs(graph,"Arad","Bucharest")
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use initialize your (priority) queue like this:

```
queue = PriorityQueue()
queue.put([0,[start]])
```

Here, `start` is a tuple representing the starting state or anything you want to represent in your way.

Then unpack it inside the `while` loop:

```
cost,path = queue.get()
x,y=path[-1]
```

You don't need to define the path var in advance.

When the goal state is reached, instead of returning the cost, just print(cost) or whatever var you want to print and return the path:

```
x,y=path[-1]
```

And, to update it when we are traversing the adjacency list of each node, you can do this:

```
queue.put([costx,path + [(x2, y2)]])
```

If you want to keep track of many things, you can keep it inside the 'priorityQueue()  (your queue).

I can add the code if you want but maybe that won't be necessary.